# Nodejs forever deployment

Tags: node.js, deployment, forever

I am working on project of Nodejs, this is the first time we have started working on nodejs. I am running few node scripts in **forever** demon, everytime if there is any update in those scripts I need to restart those scripts again, also where there are new script added I need to add them manually in forever command.

Is there any deployment tool / mechanism which can take care of restarting or starting nodejs script as soon as they are deployed on server?

Comment: there is a shipit.js (https://github.com/shipitjs/shipit) which automates that. Check out this video tutorial on how to use it: https://youtu.be/8PpBySjkWEM - basically, you run: `npx shipit deploy staging` and it takes care of the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) in favour of forever, and then use it's **Watch & Restart** functionality, explained [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/). It will then automatically restart your app when a file changes in the current directory or its subdirectories

[image]

If you want to stick with forever, it also supports similar functionality through the use of the `-w, --watch` flag which can either be passed as a parameter or loaded via the config file. Have a look at their README [here](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)